# Keys have same value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to do something like this in PHP?

```
$array = array(
            array(
                'key1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.',
                'key2'  => custom_function(key1),
                'key3'  => 'Dolores quas quis beatae. Quis modi nulla aspernatur cumque cum atque deleniti provident.',
            ), 
            array(
                'key1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.',
                'key2'  => custom_function(key1),
                'key3'  => 'Dolores quas quis beatae. Quis modi nulla aspernatur cumque cum atque deleniti provident.',
            ),
array(
                    'key1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.',
                    'key2'  => custom_function(key1),
                    'key3'  => 'Dolores quas quis beatae. Quis modi nulla aspernatur cumque cum atque deleniti provident.',
                ),
);
```

instead of typing twice the same value in both keys?

What I'm trying to do is to set the value of key2 properly during the creation of the array and not do this insead after I have created the array

```
$array['key2'] = my_custom_function($array['key1']);
```

Comment: Why not test it and find out?

Comment: yes this is possible. are you having problems?

Comment: `my_custom_function($myArray['key1'])`

Comment: What is in `my_custom_function()`?

Comment: @Epodax I tried it but php throws an error for undefined array

Comment: @Hassan Nothing specific.. I just want to run the value from a custom function I've created for formatting

Comment: @Lykos have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not with that exact syntax and actually I am not sure if you are able to do this during the creation of the array.

What you're trying to do is set value B equal to value A in the array, there's something else you could do which would be to store the contents of value A in a variable before putting it in the array like this:

```
$myValue = 'some lorum ipsum text'

$myArray = [
    'key1' => $myValue,
    'key2' => myFunction($myValue)
    //...
];
```

This way you don't have to use the method you want to avoid and it will probably be less error prone than trying to do it in the array itself even if it works perfectly fine ;)

**EDIT 1**

The OP has a nested array with more arrays in them containing the key / value pairs that need to be duplicated.

What we do here, if I make the assumption that `key1` is always the main value and `key2` is always the value you'd like to duplicate:

```
foreach ($array as $singleArray) {

    //$singleArray is now $array[i] where i = n of times looped
    //also note that $singleArray['key1'] exists here.
    $myValue = $singleArray['key1'];

    //here we update 'key2' of the array to match 'key1' after executing a function on it's value
    $singleArray['key2'] = myFunction($myValue);

}
```

If your keys already exist in the array before you start this loop.

*e.g. your arrays are filled within the main array*

Then you can safely do this.
Do note that anything in `$singleArray['key2']` will be overridden per sub-array.

Comment: I thought about this with $myValue, but what if I have many arrays like this? say for example 20.. This way I had to create 20 different variables then.. That's why I'm looking for a way to do this during the creation of the array as you said..

Comment: If you have 20 arrays you can just override $myValue every time you move on to a new array - it's not that nice to do but if you have to do it than this way would be a possibility. (remember that you can simply overwrite variables so you don't need 20, just 1 disposable one.)

Comment: The problem is that all my arrays are nested inside another parent array, so I cant override $myValue before each child-array. php throughs an error

Comment: Could you please update your answer to include the entire code running within the script? Only giving partial information gives partial answers too so I'm going to wait until you have a change to edit before I make useless assumptions ;)

Comment: I did an update to my script. The hole things look like this above

Answer (score -1):

You need to define an array first. [How to create an array?](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.',
    'key2'  => '', // has same value like key1
    'key3'  => 'Dolores quas quis beatae. Quis modi nulla aspernatur cumque cum atque deleniti provident.',
);
```

To change the value of `$array['key1']` to `$array['key1']`

```
echo $array['key2'] = $array['key1'];
```

**NOTE**

You need to define `my_custom_function()` by your end as you told on your comment! `It is for formatting`

Comment: What is in `my_custom_function()`?

Comment: My array looks like yours. I'm just asking whether is a way to do something like this: 'key2'  => my_custom_function($array['key1']).. I've tried it but I get error

Comment: Even though it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @NarendraSisodia I already Lykos about `my_custom_function()`. Please comment on his question. I have updated my answer again.